# Where is python file for exporting DAE (collada)

Tags: scripting, export, import

I found the .py file for one for exporting .obj, modified it, exported a cube and confirmed the changes (after reloading blender). Good, I have a starting point to write a script to export to my own personal 3d file format. My format is in XML so starting from the collada (.dae) script would make things far easier.

But I can't find it in with the other scripts (or anywhere else). I notice in Blender it says "Collada (Default)(.dae)" where the others don't say "default"... Is there such a script or does the "default" part mean its compiled in with blender?

Comment: AFAIK, yes, the collada exported is compiled in with blender. However [here's an alternate python based script](http://www.godotengine.org/wp/better-collada-exporter/) which claims to have more features (haven't tested it or even blender's native one tbh :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collada import/export functionality is provided through [c++ source code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/collada/) included with blender that links to an [external opencollada library](https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/OpenCOLLADA).

If you want a python example for collada have a look at the [better collada exporter](http://www.godotengine.org/wp/better-collada-exporter/) it is part of the godot project as is meant to be better than the default blender collada exporter.

Answer (score 1):

To export the current scene

```
bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath='/Users/dave/test.dae')
```

Or for more options

```
bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath='/Users/dave/test.dae', check_existing=False, filter_blender=False, filter_image=False, filter_movie=False, filter_python=False, filter_font=False, filter_sound=False, filter_text=False, filter_btx=False, filter_collada=True, filter_folder=True, filemode=8)
```

---